# Как развернуть gwt приложение на внешний ip?

Tags: gwt, java, jetty, tomcat, сервер

Собрал gwt-приложение на localhost-е. Как теперь запустить его из вне на своем компе?

Comment: разобрались? подскажите и нам)

Comment: Можно по разному. Можно поставить веб-сервер и задеплоить туда полученный в результате компиляции war. Можно написать сервер самому и использовать только контейнер сервлетов. В этих двух ситуациях приложение будет доступно по ip. Что касается моего вопроса, что-то было не так с сетевыми настройками. Еще можно установить свое приложение на открытые платформы типа Heroku или Openshift.

Answer (score 1):

Собираете war, копируете его в папку приложений веб-сервера, запускаете веб-сервер, приложение деплоится. При необходимости, перед деплоем проводите настройки веб-сервера,  коих до чёртиков и официальную документацию поразгребать придётся.